# Правильно ли употреблены однородные сказуемые?

Tags: согласование

Корректно ли употреблять два однородных сказуемых в таком виде?

> *Кот спрятался под кресло-кровать и выжидал удобного случая для реванша.*

Спрятался и выжидал отвечают на два разных вопроса, при этом являются однородными сказуемыми. Правильно ли составлено предложение в данном случае?

Comment: Александр всё правильно сказал.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь всё *правильно*, поскольку действия сказуемых приводятся в естественной последовательности: сначала завершённое действие (спрятался), выраженное глаголом совершенного вида, а затем начавшееся после него продолжающееся действие (глагол несовершенного вида "выжидал"). Даже нет необходимости обозначать начало второго действия ("теперь" выжидал) или добавлять второй глагол совершенного вида ("стал" выжидать) - и так ясно. Автор здесь не просто последовательность событий перечисляет (спрятался, начал ждать, а потом ещё что-то случилось), а готовит продолжение (что же произошло, *пока* кот "выжидал").

Answer (score 1):

Нет правила, которое требует согласовывать глаголы в виде. Известный писатель М.Веллер (кстати, выпускник филфака ЛГУ, не хухры-мухры) в своем эссе "Борьба с редактором" приводит фразу: "Он прибежал и работал".